# jQuery "change" event removed when in Knockout scope

Tags: jquery, magento, knockout.js, magento2

I don't know if it is specific to Magento 2 but an already set up HTML node with jQuery `change` event attached to it will lose its `change` event when run inside a knockout component with attached VM (view model).

**Situation in Magento:**

I moved the [product options wrapper](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml#L68) via a layout xml into a custom block

```xml
<referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
    // Custom block definition
    <move element="product.info.options.wrapper" destination="custom.block" />
</referenceBlock>
```

*That works without any issues!*

Now when wrapping around this moved block a knockout model with Magentos [custom "scope" binding](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html), all applied `onChange` events are getting removed - which means in this case the configurable option select boxes staying disabled.

The `change` events are getting applied [here in configurable.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js#L166)

```js
$(element).on('change', this, this._configure);
```

.. which also seems right for me on how to add an event.

So in my template file I do the following to wrap my knockout component (with attached VM) around this html snippet:

```html
<div class="tab-content" data-step="1" data-bind="scope:'times'">
    // all change events are removed from the configurable widget 
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product_options_wrapper'); ?>
</div>
```

Anybody knows if this a thing between KnockoutJS and jQuery or if this has something to do with Magento?

**Update:**

It seems this is a bug in Magento:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10261

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the event listeners after the ko bindings have been applied and reapply them after the observable has changed. This would happen due to the html not being there when you ran the event listeners.

Can I ask why you are using jquery event listener for the change of the value, if the input is bound by ko, you can use a subscribe:

```
self.Value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    // Logic in here
});
```

Comment: The original functionality is default Magento - product detail page, multiple configurable attributes in select boxes... and Magento uses jQuery event listeners ;-) This is perfectly fine, but I need this complete block inside a KO template to apply custom values to the markup *around* this block filters block. Does that make sense? oO

Comment: Furthermore: How would I apply the event triggers coming from Magento core JS (see link above) again?

Comment: This `$(element).on('change', this, this._configure);` needs to be fired after your `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("container"));`

Comment: To get all the select `element`s I would duplicate code from the `configurable.js` widget. I am not sure about using this approach but will try to check.